# How can I nest GeoJSON / TopoJSON geometries OR nest the generated paths with D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geojson, topojson

Problem:

I'm attempting to create an interactive map of the US in which state, county and national boundaries are displayed. Counties are shaded based on data, and hovering over a state should highlight all counties in the state, and the state should be clickable. I want to achieve this by having a SVG with the county shapes inside of state shapes, inside of a US shape.

I can generate a county map based on a CENSUS county shape file, and I can shade the states based on data in an external CSV by prepping the file with TopoJSON command line and using the following code in D3:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 600;

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa());

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("counties_pa.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

var color = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain([1, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000])
    .range(["#fff7ec", "#fee8c8", "#fdd49e", "#fdbb84", "#fc8d59", "#ef6548", "#d7301f", "#b30000", "#7f0000"]);



svg.append('g').attr('class','counties').selectAll("path").data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.cb_2014_us_county_20m).features).enter().append('path').attr('d',path).attr('style',function(d){return 'fill:'+color(d.properties.population / d.properties.area * 2.58999e6);});

});



</script>
```

This is mostly visually acceptable (except it doesn't have discrete state / national boundaries) - but is functionally inadequate. In order to apply CSS to the counties on a state hover, the counties need to be within a state shape, or grouped somehow.

What i've tried:

- Using topojson-merge in the command line to merge the counties into state shapes, and then render the state shapes separately - this helps with having discrete state borders - but I haven't figured a way to nest the counties into the respective state shapes.

What i'm working out now:

- Somehow combining a state TopoJSON file and a county TopoJSON file and nesting the counties in the states, then rendering with D3.
- Somehow using d3 to take non-nested state and county data and just nest it on the client on the client level.

In the end I would like to learn about the most effective and quickest rendering process to achieve my desired functionality.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but could you simply take the counties data and for the initial view colour all the counties in a state (and their borders) the same colour?

Comment: You could probably use properties in your topojson file to map counties to the states they belong to.  ie. have a `state` property on each county that identified the state that they belonged to, this would then allow you to select all matching counties on hover of a state.  I'm not really clear on what you're trying to achieve, other than highlight counties on state hover.  If that's it, then what I've suggested should be doable.  Where are you sourcing your county shapefiles from, and does it have the state that each county belongs to in an existing property that you can reuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a punt on your data sources, and here is what it looks like you're trying to achieve: http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/55bc9474e6d531a1c1fe

Basically, I have generated a TopoJSON file using the following command line:

```
topojson -o counties_pa.json --id-property=+GEOID -p -e POP01.txt --id-property=+STCOU -p population=+POP010210D,area=ALAND,state=+STATEFP,county=+COUNTYFP cb_2014_us_county_20m.shp cb_2014_us_state_20m.shp
```

Some explanation on this:

- `-o counties_pa.json` sets the name of the output file
- `--id-property=+GEOID` will use that property in the input file as the `id` of each output geometry
- `-p` means include all properties from the input file
- `-e POP01.txt` will pull external data in from the file `POP01.txt`.  This file is a csv file generated from the `POP01.xls` spreadsheet available from http://www.census.gov/support/USACdataDownloads.html#POP
- `--id-property=+STCOU` means that the id property from the external file (`POP01.txt`) is in the STCOU column.  This is used to match up with matching `id`s in the input file (which are in the `GEOID` property as explained above)
- `-p population=+POP010210D,area=ALAND,state=+STATEFP,county=+COUNTYFP` explicitly lists the properties that I want in the output file, so anything extra won't be included.  POP010210D is the column name for the population as at the 2010 census, so I just used that for demonstration purposes.
- `cb_2014_us_county_20m.shp cb_2014_us_state_20m.shp` are the two input files.  One for county shapes and one for state shapes.  They will each be added to the output file in seperate properties named after their filenames.

I did it this way, as you seemed to be colouring your county areas based on population density, so both population and area needed to be in the output file.  The population was pulled from the `POP01` spreadsheet and linked to each county based on the `GEOID` (which is just the state number concatentated with the county number).

I was just looking for a quick and easy way to recreate your dataset, and then add the state boundaries to it so I could post the answer.  Not sure how closely this matches your original data, but it seems to work for demonstration purposes.

From that, I took your code above and updated it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

path.state {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 600;

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa());

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("counties_pa.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

var color = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain([1, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000])
    .range(["#fff7ec", "#fee8c8", "#fdd49e", "#fdbb84", "#fc8d59", "#ef6548", "#d7301f", "#b30000", "#7f0000"]);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class','counties')
        .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.cb_2014_us_county_20m).features).enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr("id", function(d) { return "county-" + d.id; })
        .attr("data-state", function(d) { return d.properties.state; })
        .attr('style',function(d) { 
            return 'fill:'+color(d.properties.population / d.properties.area * 2.58999e6);
        })
        .on("mouseover", hoverCounty)
        .on("mouseout", outCounty);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'states')
        .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.cb_2014_us_state_20m).features).enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "state")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return "state-" + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);
    });

function hoverCounty(county) {
    d3.selectAll("path[data-state='" + county.properties.state + "']").style("opacity", .5);
}

function outCounty(county) {
    d3.select(".counties").selectAll("path").style("opacity", null);
}

</script>
```

The new and interesting bits of code are:

1. Add a `data-state` attribute to each county to determine which state it belongs to:

   ```
   .attr("data-state", function(d) { return d.properties.state; })
   ```
2. Add the state boundaries (I combined states to the TopoJSON file in the `topojson` command line)

   ```
   svg.append('g')
       .attr('class', 'states')
       .selectAll("path")
     .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.cb_2014_us_state_20m).features).enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("class", "state")
       .attr("id", function(d) { return "state-" + d.id; })
       .attr("d", path);
   });
   ```
3. Added hover handlers so you can see how I'm determining the grouping of counties into states:

   ```
   function hoverCounty(county) {
       d3.selectAll("path[data-state='" + county.properties.state + "']").style("opacity", .5);
   }

   function outCounty(county) {
       d3.select(".counties").selectAll("path").style("opacity", null);
   }
   ```
4. Tied these hover handlers to each county so they get executed at the appropriate times:

   ```
   .on("mouseover", hoverCounty)
   .on("mouseout", outCounty);
   ```

Comment: Ben, this is what I was looking for thank you for very much. I wasn't aware that you could use two shapefiles in the topojson command line. Also this approach works but I wonder if it could be less verbose by literally nesting the the counties in the states somehow, and not having to set every counties ID (with state) for use in the hover event. I've got a good point to move from and I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Could you go over the topojson command line you provided? I'm a little thrown off because i see an -id-property value (+STCOU) which doesn't exist in either file and I'm wondering if its a type or not. Also I've never worked with two files and could use a more descriptive insight .

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer, feel free to ask any further questions if needed.

Comment: In terms of doing things a different way with nesting or otherwise.  I suspect that you'll find the trade off is probably not worth it.  Processing of the data to create a new data structure that mimics the physical hierarchy would probably not clear things up that much, and you'd need to create a javascript structure that was still compatible with passing things to topojson for creating the boundaries.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. I was mostly caught up on the double --id-property option - I only learned to use comma separated values there when linking in external files. The last thing I don't completely understand is the two -p options - you're specifying that you want to keep all, and then that you want to explicitly keep only some columns - is that necessary or is  my interpretation incorrect? Also, I'm just assuming that there is no order really to the options being included, and that all of the options are basically being applied to both shape files.