# Getting selected objects in topojson object

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

So I am trying to use topojson to load a map of the US and display the 50 states. When a state is clicked, I want to the display the counties within that state. The problem I am running in to though is that based on the formatting of the topojson file, I can't figure out how to know WHICH state is clicked and therefore don't know how to grab the corresponding counties from the file.

I am using a very similar implementation to the one presented by Mike Bostock on his site here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675

I am also using his version of the topojson file which can be found here:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json

When I click on a specific state, I can look at the "this" object but that ends up being just a bunch of boundary points.

Any ideas? (I can clarify if I am being too vague as well)

Clarification:

I realized that states have an id (sometimes a few depending on islands) numbered between 1-78.

If I try to create state groupings to add to the SVG like this:

```
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "states")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(state_features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "states")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("click", clicked);
```

I can later tell which state was clicked in the function that handles clicks like so:

```
function clicked(d) {
  //can reference it in here with "this"
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

This gives me the id of the state, but it seems like counties don't correspond to a given state so I don't know how to get the counties corresponding to that state.

Comment: Are you seeing the object (like "object{ type: polygon...") or just the path?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I edited my post to be more clear

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832351/how-can-i-nest-geojson-topojson-geometries-or-nest-the-generated-paths-with-d3